# .each length gives undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

What is wrong in my `if` statement? The `else` is working, but `if` is not.`count1` gives `undefined`. The terms in the `if` statement work elsewhere, so that can't be the problem.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/api/Carts',
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
      if (val.CompanyID == JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userName')) && val.IsInCart == true) {
        var count1 = val.length;
        console.log('Shopping cart has ' + count1);
      } else {
        var count = data.length;
        console.log('Shopping cart has ' + count);
      }
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: What is `val`? Or perhaps the content of `data`?

Comment: You're comparing `CompanyID` (presumably a string or int) to the result of `JSON.parse()`, which is an object or array...?

Comment: `val` seems to be an object, if it is, it wont have a `length` property

Comment: @CalvinNunes it *might* have a `length` property. Won't be the array one but just a normal property on an object. Without the data, it's impossible to say for sure what is right or wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `data` contains the items in the shopping cart? In which case, `val` is each item.

You need to ensure that `val` is either an array as well or, if that isn't practical, you need to ensure that it has a property that stores the value you're looking for as your assignment value for `count1`.

I would suggest just evaluate the length of `data` since it contains the items in the shopping cart (see below). This would mean you don't need the else unless you want a message that says "your shopping cart is empty" or something.

Unrelated: I'd suggest you could make your code a little cleaner.

I've altered your code to also clean up the if statement:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/api/Carts',
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
      let uname = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userName'));
      if (val.CompanyID == uname && val.IsInCart == true) {
        var count1 = data.length;
        console.log('Shopping cart has ' + count1);
      }
    });
  }
})
```

HTH

## EDIT 1

Per your comment:

`.each()` is giving you a single item (`val`) which can't give you a number of items. So since it looks like you're trying to output the number of items in the shopping cart, what you might want is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/api/Carts',
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
  },
  success: function(data) {
    // Get number of items.
    let count = data.length;
    console.log('Shopping car thas ' + count);

    // Get details about each item.
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
      let uname = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userName'));
      if (val.CompanyID == uname && val.IsInCart == true) {
        console.log('This item is a ' + val.Name); // Example.
      }
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes, data is items in shopping cart. But I want only those items, what .each is giving (terms in if), not all data. Now I get all data. In my example I had that else-statement for test purpose. And thanks for cleaning, I'm just learning this.

Comment: Okay, so I updated the answer. Remember that `.each()` gives you access to each item in the collection. If you want to get a number of items in the collection, you don't do it in the .each(). There's more logic involved if you're trying to get a number of items for this user or that are in the cart, but thats for another question.

Comment: Yes, that is the question, how to get number of items in shopping cart for this user.  I just didn't knew it would be so hard..

Comment: That's not the question you're asking though. The question you're asking is why does your `.each().length` give undefined value. For what you want to do,  create a counter before the `.each()` and increment it inside the `.each()` and that'll give you the number of items in the shopping cart for the user. https://jsfiddle.net/j3rs457v/